# User.Identity is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to check if an user is logged in or not. In View I'm checking it like this;

```
                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    //links...
                }
                else
                {
                    //links...
                }
```

always returns false and Identity is empty although I SignInAsync in my login function. I tried to change the order of the configure method usings but it didn't work.
Here is my startup and login function.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("Appsettings:Secret").Value);
        services.AddDbContext<BiHaberContext>();
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<BiHaberContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        });

        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));


        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
                options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddScoped<ISemesterService, SemesterManager>();
        services.AddScoped<IDepartmentService, DepartmentManager>();
        services.AddScoped<ICourseService, CourseManager>();
        services.AddScoped<IAnnouncementService, AnnouncementManager>();
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddResponseCaching();
        services.AddMemoryCache();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader());
        app.UseResponseCaching();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        });
    }
```

Login:

```
 [HttpPost("/login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(myContent, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
        using (var postTask = await ApiHelper.ApiClient.PostAsync("Auth/Login", stringContent))
        {
            string jwt = await postTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(JwtExtension.CorrectJwtFormat(jwt));
            var claims = token.Payload.Claims.ToList();
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                AllowRefresh = true, ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(1), IsPersistent = true
            };
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),authProperties);
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }
    }
```

API works well and brings me 7 claims and claimsIdentity contains them as well. And redirecting to index. What did I do wrong I just couldn't figure out.
Added: Also I can not use Authorize attribute. So there is no authorizing anywhere.

Comment: Try removing the second calls to `AddAuthentication` and `AddAuthorization` in `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: I did, unfortunately nothing happened different.

Comment: Do you have to use the same `BiHaberContext` dbContext for your regular database, as well as your Identity stores? I am afraid calling `.AddDbContext<BiHaberContext>();` and `.AddIdentity()` right after that might cause you the problem. And yea remove the second calls to `AddAuthentication()` and `AddAuthorization()`.

Comment: if i delete my `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>() .AddEntityFrameworkStores<BiHaberContext>();` it's working actually. Yeah. But I'm using this guy in my API to make some user things. I guess I need to remove asp.net Identity from my database I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I delete this line

```
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<BiHaberContext>();
```

It worked. Identity is overriding my own claims. Thanks to @David Liang